# One listener for many Android dialogs

Tags: android, android-dialog

I've created a few TimePickerDialogs like that (each timepicker for the corresponding editview):

```
TimePickerDialog(context, this,
                 cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                 cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                 true).show()
```

When listening them all inside the Activity:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
}
```

How should I determine which dialog is active? I couldn't find any ways like dialog's names or tags to resolve this problem.
The same problem with the AlertDialog class.

Answer (score 3):

**TimerPickerDialog** contain **TimerPicker** with id `R.id.timePicker` so that you can find TimePicker in **TimerPickerDialog** by:

```
TimerPickerDialogInstance.findViewById(R.id.timePicker)
```

And:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    if (view == dialog1.findViewById(R.id.timePicker)) {
        //dialog1
    }
    else if (view == dialog2.findViewById(R.id.timePicker)) {
       //dialog2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save all Dialog into a ArrayList like that:

```
ArrayList<TimePickerDialog> timePickers = new ArrayList<>();
timePickers.add(new TimePickerDialog(...));
```

Then in **onTimeSet** iterate over all dialogs and ask, wether they are opened or not:

```
for(TimePickerDialog dialog: timePickers)
{
    if(dialog.isShowing())
    { // do something... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very good solution, but you can try it:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    if (view == dialog1.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.timePicker)){
        ...
    }
    else if (view == dialog2.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.timePicker)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can save references to timePicker from dialog in variable for optimization.

This solution may be not work on all devices because use internal implementation of time picker. It may changes in different versions.

Answer (score 0):

I like [**phongvan**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218165/4773117) solution but I would improve this solution by using setTag

```
TimerPickerDialogInstance.findViewById(R.id.timePicker).setTag(TimerPickerDialogInstance);
```

And:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    TimerPickerDialog dialog = (TimerPickerDialog) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker).getTag();
}
```